Error 7874 en consulta Access con código VBA
Cordial saludo equipo espero se encuentren bien, agradezco me colaboren por favor a dar con el siguiente inconveniente (Error 7874 en Access):
Resulta que de modo previo tengo una consulta que cree en Access y está funcionando bien, la sintaxis es la siguiente:
SELECT Max(Observaciones) AS Saldo_anterior
FROM Concepto
WHERE Concepto.IdCtaCobro IN (SELECT TOP 1 RecibodeIngresos.IdCtaCobro
FROM RecibodeIngresos
WHERE Númdedocidentif=[Forms]![frm_ProveedoresRecibodeingresosconcepto]![Númdedocidentif]);

Al implementarla en un botón en lenguaje VBA, cuya consulta anterior se convierte en el siguiente código:
 Sub frm_ProvRecibdeIngConc()
   Dim sSql As String, Saldoant As DAO.Recordset
   sSql = "SELECT Max(Observaciones) as Saldo_anterior " & _
   "FROM Concepto WHERE Concepto.IdCtaCobro IN (SELECT TOP 1 RecibodeIngresos.IdCtaCobro " & _
   "FROM RecibodeIngresos WHERE Númdedocidentif= '" & [Forms]![frm_ProveedoresRecibodeingresosconcepto]![Númdedocidentif] & "');"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery sSql
End Sub

Al dar clic en el botón, me aparece el siguiente error:
Microsoft Access no encuentra el objeto
‘SELECT MAX(Observaciones) as Saldo_anterior FROM Concepto WHERE 
Concepto.IdCtaCobro IN (SELECT TOP 1 RecibodeIngresos.IdCtaCobro FROM RecibodeIngresos WHERE Númdedocidentif=’0402’);’ 

No entiendo por qué aparece dicho error, si la consulta dentro del lenguaje VBA del Access, tiene todos los criterios de desarrollo incluso con el manejo del cuadro de texto cuando este maneja campos dependientes del formulario principal.
Muchas gracias por la colaboración que me puedan brindar.
